# VERY simple Canvas paint works in Fx not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

I was shown [this script](http://plungjan.name/test/testcanvas.html) which is a modification from http://www.robodesign.ro/coding/canvas-paint/20090423/

It works very well in Fx 10 but not at all in Chrome.

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/test/testcanvas.html)

I got rid of the Chrome warning about the deprecated event.layerX/Y by swapping the offsetX and layerX but it still does not draw.

Must be something very simple.
**UPDATE**: and it was - commenting out two `context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);` did the trick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Paint</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
      #container { position: relative; }
      #imageView { border: 1px solid #000; }
    --></style>
  </head>
  <body BGCOLOR="#CCFFFF"> 

    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="imageView" width="700" height="643" margin: 0 auto>
        <p>Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web 
        application.  We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the 
        supported browsers listed below, or draw the image you want using an 
        offline tool.</p>
        <p>Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a 
          href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>, <a 
          href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a 
          href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.</p>
      </canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
/* © 2009 ROBO Design
 * http://www.robodesign.ro
 */

// Keep everything in anonymous function, called on window load.
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas, context, tool;

  function init () {
    // Find the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvas.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    };
    img.src="  PainDiagram.png";

    // Pencil tool instance.
    tool = new tool_pencil();

    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }

  // This painting tool works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
  // movements.
  function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
    // This starts the pencil drawing.
    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.globalAlpha=0.01;
        context.shadowColor="red";
        context.shadowBlur=10;
        context.strokeStyle = "red"; // line color
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only 
    // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down 
    // the mouse button).
    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        //var p = context.getImageData(ev._x, ev._y, 1, 1).data; 
        //if(p[0]==255 && p[1]==204 && p[2]==153){
            context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.stroke();
        //}
      }
    };

    // This is called when you release the mouse button.
    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  }

  // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
  // position relative to the canvas element.


  function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera and WebKit
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }  
    else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } 

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }

  init();

}, false); }

// vim:set spell spl=en fo=wan1croql tw=80 ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sta et ai cin fenc=utf-8 ff=unix:

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);` from `this.mousemove`.

The `moveTo()` method creates a new subpath, so you were telling the canvas to apply a stroke to a path with a length of zero pixels. Firefox apparently supports this. See the [canvas documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-moveto) for more information.

Comment: You just missed a bounty. Thanks!